# Using AVAudioPlayer for piano samples -- memory management

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I am writing a simple iOS app that will include a piano.

I only need something very basic, and I'm probably going with this approach:

- have a single .mp3 for every piano key
- use AVAudioPlayer to play the .mp3s as appropriate

My understanding is that one `AVAudioPlayer` instance can only be used with one sound. Therefore, I'd have to create many `AVAudioPlayer`s (88 to be precise), one for every piano key.

My question is, how memory-intensive is `AVAudioPlayer`? Can I just initialize the program by creating 88 `AVAudioPlayer`s, keeping them in memory, and using them as appropriate? Or is the memory footprint of an `AVAudioPlayer` too big, and should I only alloc/release the `AVAudioPlayer`s as necessary? If so, will allocating/releasing the players be quick enough so that the user doesn't notice any lag?

Comment: Why not try creating 10 or so `AVAudioPlayer` instances and monitor the memory footprint in Instruments? If it looks ok then ramp up the instances and see how it goes.

Comment: Also, I would recommend using the IMA4 (CAF) audio format, as it would put less processing stress on the iDevice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project uses OpenAL [SoundBankPlayer](https://github.com/hollance/SoundBankPlayer) as a solution for that functionality. Another approach is to use a soundFont and a Sampler AudioUnit. Very optimized for music creation type apps. Good details and source code: [AudioGraph](http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html)